# SQL - Keep only the first and last record of each day

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that stores simple log data:

```
CREATE TABLE chronicle (
    id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
    data1 VARCHAR(256),
    data2 VARCHAR(256),
    time DATETIME
);
```

The table is approaching 1m records, so I'd like to start consolidating data.

I want to be able to take the first and last record of each `DISTINCT(data1, data2)` each day and delete all the rest.

I know how to just pull in the data and process it in whatever language I want then delete the records with a huge [`IN (...)` query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379357/what-is-the-best-way-to-select-multiple-rows-by-id-in-sql), but it seems like a better alternative would to use SQL directly (am I wrong?)

I have tried several queries, but I'm not very good with SQL beyond JOINs.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT id, Max(time), Min(time)
FROM   (SELECT id, data1 ,data2, time, Cast(time AS DATE) AS day
        FROM chronicle) AS initial
GROUP BY day;
```

This gets me the first and last time for each day, but it's not separated out by the data (i.e. I get the last record of each day, not the last record for each distinct set of data for each day.)  Additionally, the `id` is just for the Min(time).

The information I've found on this particular problem is only for finding the the last record of the day, not each last record for sets of data.

**IMPORTANT:** I want the first/last record  for each `DISTINCT(data1, data2)` for each day, not just the first/last record for each day in the table.  There will be more than 2 records for each day.

**Solution:**
My solution thanks to Jonathan Dahan and Gordon Linoff:

```
SELECT o.data1, o.data2, o.time FROM chronicle AS o JOIN (
    SELECT Min(id) as id FROM chronicle GROUP BY DATE(time), data1, data2
    UNION SELECT Max(id) as id FROM test_chronicle GROUP BY DATE(time), data1. data2
) AS n ON o.id = n.id;
```

From here it's a simple matter of referencing the same table to delete rows.

Comment: Can the ids be relied on as being sequential? Meaning will id 10 always have a date/time equal to or before id 11?

Comment: What is the reason you want to remove the old records? Is it to do with poor query performance? Or disk space usage?

Comment: @JonathanDahan they definitely won't be sequential since records are being removed. But I think you're actually meaning monotonically increasing. From what I can tell, mysql's `auto_increment` is by default monotonically increasing meaning if id_a < id_b then date_a <= date_b.

Comment: @JonathanDahan both. There's a lot of duplicate records.

Comment: Ok so for the performance, you can simply add an index to solve the problem. For the space, then yes you need to delete the records.

Comment: @JonathanDahan I already have indexes on every column in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will improve performance when searching on dates.

```
ALTER TABLE chronicle
ADD INDEX `ix_chronicle_time` (`time` ASC);
```

This will delete the records:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #tmp_ids (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO #tmp_ids (id)
SELECT
    min(id)
FROM
    chronicle
GROUP BY
    CAST(day as DATE),
    data1,
    data2
UNION
SELECT
    Max(id)
FROM
    chronicle
GROUP BY
    CAST(day as DATE),
    data1,
    data2;

DELETE FROM
    chronicle
WHERE
    ID not in (select id FROM #tmp_ids)
    AND date <= '2015-01-01'; -- if you want to consider all dates, then remove this condition
```

Comment: Thanks. This has the same problem as the answer by @Gordan Linoff: I get the first/last record of each day, not the last record for each distinct set of data for each day. I added an important note at the bottom.

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me exactly, but the concept works. I didn't know that GROUP BY on all values was all that was needed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's also important to note that when you do a group by, you can't select anything that isn't in the group by otherwise you will get incorrect results. The only exception to this is when you are using aggregate functions such as min(), max(), avg(), sum(), count(), etc. Some mysql installations allow doing bad group bys (legacy support), while others enforce good group bys only.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  You just need to join back to get the original information.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM chronicle c JOIN
     (SELECT date(time) as day, min(time) as mint, max(time) as maxt
      FROM chronicle
      GROUP BY date(time)
     ) cc
     ON c.time IN (cc.mint, cc.maxt);
```

Note that the `join` condition doesn't need to include `day` explicitly because it is part of the `time`.  Of course, you could add `date(c.time) = cc.day` if you wanted to.

Instead of deleting rows in your original table, I would suggest that you make a new table.  Something lie this:

```
create table ChronicleByDay like chronicle;

insert into ChronicleByDay
    SELECT c.*
    FROM chronicle c JOIN
         (SELECT date(time) as day, min(time) as mint, max(time) as maxt
          FROM chronicle
          GROUP BY date(time)
         ) cc
         ON c.time IN (cc.mint, cc.maxt);
```

That way, you can have the more detailed information if you ever need it.

Comment: Thanks! That does fix the problem for getting both min and max, but still has the other problem: I get the first/last record of each day, not the last record for each distinct set of data for each day.